# Dihedral group problem

Tags: abstract-algebra

How is the order of $G=\{ x,y \ \lvert \ x^3= y^3= (xy)^3 =1 \}$ infinity(Abstract Algebra by Dummit Foote problem). As far as my knowledge is concerned its order is finite. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

$(xy)^3 = 1$, hence terms of the form $(xy) $ are forced to collapse. The same thing happens with $x$ and $y$.

However, you have no relation that can reduce powers of $(yx)$, so there is an infinite family of terms $(yx)^n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ which cannot be collapsed under the given presentation. Hence, the group has infinite order

Comment: This is not the correct explanation. Just write out what such a power is to see that something does cancel. However, one can consider powers of $xyx$.

Comment: still i am not able to understand @Siddharth Bhat and Tobias Kildetoft